# Executing PowerShell 7 scripts from a .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-remoting, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script from inside a .NET Framework based application. The script requires PowerShell 7 / PowerShell Core. I can execute Windows PowerShell 5.1, but there seems to be no way to run the script with PowerShell 7. A simple `pwsh script.ps1` doesn't suffice, since I have to be able to capture its output and pass some variables and credentials to it. I've tried remoting already, but it's broken because of a strange bug in PowerShell 7, that the team is already aware of.
Does anyone have a tip how to run PowerShell 7 / PowerShell Core from inside .NET Framework?

Thank you

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Choosing the right PowerShell NuGet package for your .NET project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/choosing-the-right-nuget-package?view=powershell-7.2), [Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?source=recommendations&view=powershell-7.2#net-framework-vs-net-core)

Comment: According to [Resolving PowerShell module assembly dependency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts?view=powershell-7.3#powershell-and-net): _different versions of PowerShell run on different .NET implementations. In general, PowerShell 5.1 and below run on .NET Framework, while PowerShell 6 and above run on .NET Core. These two implementations of .NET load and handle assemblies differently. This means that resolving dependency conflicts can vary depending on the underlying .NET platform_.

Comment: If you desire to use PowerShell in a .NET Framework project you'll have to use [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0) to run PowerShell.

Comment: You can call the executables in the following folder : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell

Comment: I'm not sure if it's of any help in this situation, but perhaps the PS [#Requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.3) attribute gives you an idea.

Comment: The PowerShell 7 executable location is stored in the registry in a subkey under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\InstalledVersions`. In Win 10, the default installation location is `%ProgramFiles%\PowerShell`. For PowerShell < 6, see the subkey(s) under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell`.